# Как на erlang файл с разделителем "\r\n" прочитать в binary режиме?

Tags: erlang

Как на erlang файл с разделителем "\r\n" прочитать в binary режиме, а потом перевести в массив строк разделяя каждый новый элемент через "\r\n" ?

Comment: А что у Вас не получилось? Или Вы просто хотите примеры посмотреть?

Кстати, Вам точно нужно читать в массив, а не в список?

Comment: В почте видел ваш комментарий с исходником, но вопрос уже удалён. Текст мне показался весьма странным. Нельзя ли повторить, думаю, что там есть что обсуждать. В плане подходов к языку.

Comment: нужны примеры, если массив быстрее списка то в массив

Answer (score 1):

```
{ok, Bin} = file:read_file("input.txt"),
Lines = binary:split(Bin, <<"\r\n">>, [global]),
```